# Substitution method for solving reccurences

Tags: recursion

I have recently had trouble with understanding the substitution method for solving reccurences. I watched few on-line lectures about the problem, but sadly it did not tell me much (in one of them I heard that it is based on guessing, which made me even more confused) and I am looking for some tips. My objective is to solve three different reccurence functions using substitution method, find their time complexity and their values for T(32).

> ***Function 1*** is defined as:
>   T(1) = 1
>   T(n) = T(n-1) + n for n > 1

I started off by listing first few executions:

```
T(2) = T(2-1)+2 = 1+2
T(3) = T(3-1)+3 = 1+2+3
T(4) = T(4-1)+4 = 1+2+3+4
T(5) = T(5-1)+5 = 1+2+3+4+5
...
T(n) = 1+2+...+(n-1)+n = n(n+1)/2
```

Then I proved by induction, that *T(1) = 1* using the formula for sum of the first *n* natural numbers, and then that it is also true for *n+1*. It was pretty clear to me, but I am not sure whether this is substitution method. Also knowing the formula *T(n) = n(n+1)/2* I easily calculated T(32) = 528 and counted the time complexity, which is O(n^2).

In examples **(2)** and **(3)** I only need solution for ***n=2^k*** when *k* is a natural number, but it would be nice if you recommended me any articles showing how to get these for all *n* as well (but I suppose it is way harder than that).

> ***Function 2*** is defined as:
>   T(1) = 0
>   T(n) = T(n/2) + 1 for even n > 1
>   T(n) = T((n+1)/2) + 1 for odd n > 1

As I was allowed to prove it only for *n=2^k* and based on my gained knowledge I tried to do it following way:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + 1
     = T(n/4) + 1 + 1     = T(n/4) + 2
     = T(n/8) + 1 + 2     = T(n/8) + 3
     = T(n/16) + 1 + 3    = T(n/16) + 4
     = T(n/2^i) + i     // where i <= k, according to tutorials
```

And this is the moment where I get stuck and I cannot proceed further. I suppose that my calculations are correct, but I am not sure how should I look for a formula, which would satisfy this function. After I get the right formula, calculating T(32) or time complexity will not be a problem.

> ***Function 3*** is defined as:
>   T(1) = 1
>   T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1 for even n > 1
>   T(n) = T((n – 1)/2) + T((n+1)/2) + 1 for odd n > 1

My calculations:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1
     = 2(2T(n/4)+1) + 1 = 4T(n/4) + 3
     = 4(2T(n/8)+1) + 3 = 8T(n/8) + 7
     = iT(n/2^i) + 2^i - 1
```

And again it comes to the formula, which I am not sure how should be rewritten.

Basically, does substitution method for solving reccurences means finding and iterative formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restudying the topic I found what I did wrong and not to leave my question unanswered, I will try to do it.

The first function is calculated well, induction proof is also correct - nothing to add here.

> When it comes to the **second function** where I got stuck, I did not
>   pay attention that I was actually using a substitution **n=2^k**. This
>   is how it should look:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + 1
     = T(n/4) + 1 + 1     = T(n/4) + 2
     = T(n/8) + 1 + 2     = T(n/8) + 3
     = T(n/16) + 1 + 3    = T(n/16) + 4
     = T(n/2^k) + k 
     = T(1) + k 
     = k
```

**Induction proof** that *T(2^k) = k* works:
***Base case:*** k=1, then T(2^1) = T(2) = 1. *(it cannot be k=0, as 2^0 is not bigger than 1)*
***Inductive step:*** assume T(2^k) = k, we want to show T(2^(k+1)) = k+1. As *2^k=n*, then *2^(k+1) = 2*2^k = 2n*.

```
T(2n) = T(n) + 1
      = T(n/2) + 1 + 1
      = T(n/4) + 2 + 1
      = T(n/8) + 3 + 1
      = T(1) + k + 1
      = k + 1.
```

***Time complexity:*** O(log n)
***T(32)*** = T(2^5) = 5

> In the **third function** I missed that every time the function called
>   itself, the value has doubled.

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1
     = 2(2T(n/4)+1) + 1     = 4T(n/4) + 3
     = 4(2T(n/8)+1) + 3     = 8T(n/8) + 7
     = 8(2T(n/16)+1) + 7    = 16T(n/16) + 15
     = 16(2T(n/32)+1) + 15  = 32T(n/32) + 31
     = 2^k*T(n/2^i) + 2^k - 1
     = 2^k*T(1) + 2^k - 1
     = 2^k + 2^k - 1
     = 2^(k+1) - 1
```

**Induction proof** that *T(2^k) = 2^(k+1)-1* works:
***Base case:*** k=1, then T(2^1) = T(2) = 3. Original function T(2) = 2T(1)+1 = 2+1 = 3, so base case is true.
***Inductive step:*** assume T(2^k) = 2^(k+1)-1, we want to show  T(2^(k+1)) = 2^(k+2)-1. Similarly, as in the second function, *2^k=n*, so *2^(k+1) = 2*2^k = 2n*.

```
T(2n) = 2T(n) + 1
      = 2(2T(n/2)+1) + 1    = 4T(n/2) + 3
      = 4(2T(n/4)+1) + 1    = 8T(n/4) + 7
      = 8(2T(n/8)+1) + 1    = 16T(n/8) + 15
      = 2^(k+1) + 2^(k+1) - 1
      = 2*2^(k+1) - 1
      = 2^(k+2) - 1.
```

We could also take a look at first few elements for T(n), which are 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, etc., so T(n) = 2n-1

***Time complexity:*** O(n)
***T(32)*** = T(2^5) = 2^(5+1) - 1 = 64 - 1 = 63